# Windows Batch - Rename files with period before extension

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm on Windows 10, and I'm writing a batch file to convert many images from one format to another and renaming a helper file that generates more information about each image. Here's an example:

```
test.tif
test.tif.thing
```

If I'm converting to a format like png, I want to rename **test.tif.thing** to **test.png.thing**. Here's the existing script I have, which doesn't work at all due to me experimenting with numerous options, but it should hopefully highlight the problem:

```
for %%q in (*.tif.thing) do (
    ren "%%q" "%%~pq%%~nq"
)
timeout 100
```

The main issue I'm having is removing the ".tif" when renaming the file, since ".thing" is technically the actual extension, so the filename is "thing.tif" without the extension. I looked into using variables to remove the characters from the string, but I never managed to get them to work, and if possible I'd like to know a cleaner solution to make this scale better should the filenames change in the future. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second level of `FOR` to remove the inner extension from the file name

```
for %%A in (*.tif.thing) do (
    REM %%A is filename.tif.thing
    REM %%~nA is filename.tif
    for %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        REM %%~nB is filename
        ECHO ren "%%~A" "%%~nB.png.thing"
    )
)
```

The `ren` command is disarmed to prevent actual renaming of files while testing the script. Remove `ECHO` to enable renaming.